# malloc crashes program on 4th call

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, crash, malloc

I'm making the game atoms in C where people take turns putting atoms into grid spaces. I'm trying to implement a move tracking system wherein every time they make a move, the moves array is increased by one. Not very efficient I know (and I know I don't check malloc return value), but just trying to get it at least working for now. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
int move_count_temp = (game->move_count)+1;
move_t* moves;

//Check if it's first move
if (game->moves == NULL) moves = (move_t*)malloc(sizeof(move_t*));
else moves = (move_t*)malloc(move_count_temp*sizeof(move_t*));

// Copy old moves over
for (int i=0; i<game->move_count;i++) {
    moves[i].x = game->moves[i].x;
    moves[i].y = game->moves[i].y;
}

//Copy current move
moves[move_count_temp-1].x = y_coordinate;
moves[move_count_temp-1].y = x_coordinate;

// Free old moves pointer and assign new one
free(game->moves);
game->moves = moves;
game->move_count = move_count_temp;
```

The problem is on the 4th move it crashes on the 4th line in that sample, when mallocing `moves`. I've been trying to fix it for a while and just don't know why it's happening. Any insight would help, thanks.

P.S. The game struct has a pointer to a moves struct, and this is the move_t struct;

```
struct move_t {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These allocations are wrong:

```
if (game->moves == NULL) moves = (move_t*)malloc(sizeof(move_t*));
else moves = (move_t*)malloc(move_count_temp*sizeof(move_t*));
```

You need to allocate space for `move_t` structures, not pointers to `move_t` structures. The canonical way to do this helps avoid such mistakes:

```
if (game->moves == NULL) {
    moves = malloc(sizeof *moves);
} else {
    moves = malloc(sizeof *moves * move_count_temp);
}
```

That is, there is no reason to cast the result of calls to `malloc()` in C, this only serves to clutter the code. And, using an identifier instead of an explicit type in the `sizeof` operand helps avoid the error in the posted code, as well as making the code easier to maintain.

That said, it seems like the posted code should use `realloc()` instead of `malloc()` and `free()` to reallocate `game->moves`.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome help! Looks like it's working now (I cast because I'm using a C++ compiler and it gives an error otherwise).

Comment: Yes, C++ does require the cast.

Comment: @Jayce444 Use a C compiler or code in C++, you can not compile C-Code in a C++ compiler (only C headers), C is not a subset of C++ and C++ is not a superset of C.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123-- of course C++ is not a superset of C, and while I agree that you can't in general compile C code with a C++ compiler, it is possible to write code using a subset of C that will compile as C++; doing so requires casting the result of `malloc()`.